# VBA for MS Access: write to an excel file without opening, write to last row, save and close

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA in MS Access for the first time and cannot get the following right:
**Launch an excel file** (without actually opening the file), then **write to the last row** in the excel file, and then **save** the file (with the same path and name as before, essentially replace the previous file), then **close** the excel file.

Please assist! So far I can write to an excel file, but cannot save and close without closing the whole MS Access application.
If you could please give a sample of working code to do the above, I will tailor it for my requirements.

Thanks!
Christine

Comment: Please share the part of your code where you open and try to save the file.

Comment: And also part where you set the pointer to the workbook will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in order to update and save a file like you want to, you have to open it first- so it is a little confusing/contradictory when you say that you don't want to 'actually open' an excel file... I took it to meant that you just don't want the excel application showing- which you would want something like this:

```
Public Sub demoCode()
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
Dim targetWB As Workbook
Dim targetRange As Range

'Create new Excel Application
Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
'Keep hidden
excelApp.Visible = False

'Have new Excel App open workbook
Set targetWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Filename.xlsm")

'Set targetRange to 1 row past the first sheet's usedrange
Set targetRange = targetWB.Sheets(1).Range(targetWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.address)(targetWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)

'Paste @ targetRange

'Close and save workbook
targetWB.Close (True)
'Close Excel App
excelApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Comment: Using Excel Objects requires a reference to `Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library`

Comment: Yes, like @gizlmo said, make sure you include any necessary object libraries.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm getting the error "argument not optional" at Set targetRange = excelApp.Range. Any idea what this is?

Comment: On which line? Set TargetRange doesn't use excelApp so can you please clarify-